# I want to add a dynamic link property to a column of a grid that takes a parameter from another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to set a dynamic link to a column in grid. I fill grid in the .cs file by reading from a webservis I can show the data on the page but ı cannot set a dynamic link to a column How can I do this ?

How I fill grid is as follows;

```
    public DataTable FillGrid(decimal CurrentUserID)
    {        
        SasBanaUygunIslerEkleRequest sasBanaUygunIslerEkleRequest = new SasBanaUygunIslerEkleRequest();
        sasBanaUygunIslerEkleRequest.IstProfilKayitNo = ((int)CurrentUserID);
        SasLocalServiceBLL sasLocalServiceBLL = new SasLocalServiceBLL();
        ServisSonucBE<List<SasBanaUygunIslerEkleResponse>> resp = sasLocalServiceBLL.BanaUygunIslerEkle(sasBanaUygunIslerEkleRequest);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("TALEPNO", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("BASLANGICTARIHI", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("BITISTARIHI", typeof(string));

        for (int index = 0; index < resp.Veri.Count; index++)
        {
            SasBanaUygunIslerEkleResponse var;
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            if (resp.Veri.ToArray()[index].IstIsgucuIstemiKayitNo != null)
            {
                row[0] = resp.Veri.ToArray()[index].IstIsgucuIstemiKayitNo;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(row);

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

I want to set link property to the first field. I want to change link page depending on condition.

```
            if (SecurityContext.IsUser && SecurityContext.CurrentUser != null && SecurityContext.CurrentUser.IsInternalUser)
                {
                    object isverenTur = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(e.Row.DataItem, "ISVERENTUR");
                    object userId = CurrentQueryHashedUserID;
                    if (userId != null)
                    {
                        literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetailsImd('{0}','{1}','{2}');\">{0}</a>", isgucuIstemiNo, isverenTur, userId);
                    }
                    else
                        literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetails('{0}');\">{0}</a>", isgucuIstemiNo);

                }
                else
                {
                    literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetails('{0}');\">{0}</a>", isgucuIstemiNo);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a dynamic link in a column of a GridView in ASP.NET WebForms, you can use the TemplateField control. Instead of directly binding the column to the data, you can define a template inside the TemplateField, allowing you to customize the content and include a dynamic link.

Here's how you can do it:

- In your .aspx page, add a GridView control and define a TemplateField for the column where you want the dynamic link.

```
<asp:GridView ID="YourGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TALEPNO">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="literal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <!-- Add other columns here -->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

- In the code-behind (.cs file), handle the RowDataBound event of the GridView. In this event, you can dynamically set the content of the Literal control based on your conditions and create the dynamic link.

```cs
protected void YourGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        if (rowView != null)
        {
            // Access the data for the current row
            string isgucuIstemiNo = rowView["TALEPNO"].ToString();
            string isverenTur = rowView["ISVERENTUR"].ToString();
            object userId = CurrentQueryHashedUserID;

            Literal literal = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("literal");

            if (SecurityContext.IsUser && SecurityContext.CurrentUser != null && SecurityContext.CurrentUser.IsInternalUser)
            {
                if (userId != null)
                {
                    literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetailsImd('{0}','{1}','{2}');\">{0}</a>", isgucuIstemiNo, isverenTur, userId);
                }
                else
                {
                    literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetails('{0}');\">{0}</a>", isgucuIstemiNo);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                literal.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"javascript:PopupJobDetails('{0}');\">{0}</a>", isgucuIstemiNo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Don't forget to wire up the RowDataBound event in the Page_Load method of your .cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Bind your GridView here
        decimal currentUserId = GetCurrentUserId(); // Replace this with the actual way to get the user ID
        DataTable dt = FillGrid(currentUserId);
        YourGridView.DataSource = dt;
        YourGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```